# Automatic weights deformation on character mesh

Tags: animation, mesh

I tried rigging a character with automatic weights and did, but it deformed the mesh severely, I did remove doubles, recalculating normals, etc, but nothing worked. Any ideas for what the cause of the problem might be?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. Since your question concerns a very specific problem, it would be helpful if you could upload your .blend file, so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: Sure, Here we go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18YmSS687VcnuIRNudWTifcpGmRNIqFkQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

That is the IK-Chain's doing. If you switch from Pose Position to Rest Position, you can tell, that your mesh is still ok.

This is however a very easy fix: All you need to do is **adjust the roll of the bone that has the IK-Constraint on it**. You do by selecting the bone in Pose Mode and the going to the Properties Window and Bone Constraints Tab.

[image: Changing IK-Chains Pole Target Roll]

[image]

Comment: thank you mate you really are a life saver;)

Comment: You are very welcome! Don't forget to mark the question solved. Well, if it IS solved, that is.